# Copy/paste issue in Ubuntu virtual machine (QEMU-KVM) with Awesome window manager

Tags: ubuntu, copy-paste, linux-kvm, qemu, awesome-wm

I have Ubuntu 12.10 virtual machine running in QEMU-KVM. Copy/paste between host and vm works fine when using Unity as window manager but not while using Awesome.

What is the difference between those? How can I configure copy/paste to work also in Awesome?

I'm using spice-vdagent (if that is somehow relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by my friend.

In addition to spice-vdagentd (daemon, started at boot time) also spice-vdagent (client) needs to be started.

Unity had spice-vdagent in startup applications, so added the same command to Awesome startup.

```
root      1831  0.0  0.0  15124   940 ?        Ss   Jan16   0:08 /usr/sbin/spice-vdagentd
kride     2059  0.0  0.0  27212   980 ?        Ss   Jan16   0:01 /usr/bin/spice-vdagent
```